# piezo and 3v LED in series to 3v battery

Tags: led, batteries, piezo

I'm a complete newbie to electronics.  This piezo I have works with a 3v battery, and this green 3v LED works with the 3v battery, but when I combine both the piezo and LED in series on the 3V battery, neither of them work.  I know both the piezo and LED are omni directional, but even when I turn around the LED and try the battery both ways around it's not working. It should be so simple, how do I get this to work?

Comment: because in series there resistance adds up causing a decrease in current,you will have to increase your source,use Oka's the formula,but don't connect them in parallel as that might reduce the resistance causing the LED to blow.Calculate voltage for each component and then use suitable rating battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piezo buzzer and LED in series with 3v battery are not working because the voltage at the buzzer and the LED are not 3v anymore.

Voltage at the buzzer:

\$ V_{buzzer} = \large \frac{ R_{buzzer}} {R_{buzzer} + R_{led}} * V_{source}\$

Voltage at the LED:

\$ V_{led} = \large \frac{ R_{led}} {R_{buzzer} + R_{led}} * V_{source}\$

For example, if LED and buzzer resistance both of them are 200 Ohm, then the voltage at buzzer and LED are 1.5v. You may look at their datasheet to find exact LED & buzzer resistance.

For a good practise, always use a resistor in series with your LED, use a 100 Ohm resistor for 3v power supply or battery. This resistor is for limiting current.

If you would like to turn on some devices at same time, connect them in parallel.
For example: LED+Rseries are parallel with buzzer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great explanation. I'm still getting my head around the math. To clarify what you wrote above, can we also say; `Voltage at the buzzer` is equal to the `resistance of buzzer` divided by `resistance of buzzer plus resistance of LED` multiply by the `voltage source`?

Comment: Yes correct. Buzzer & LED in series act as voltage divider https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider